# Install partly downloaded updates in Debian

Tags: debian, partition, upgrade, aptitude, software-updates

From time to time I update my [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) by running:

```
aptitude update && aptitude full-upgrade
```

but before running it I often forget or deliberately skip running [`aptitude clean`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-clean-aptitude-cache/) which removes old packages from [`/var/cache/apt/archives`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space).

Recently I forgot to run `aptitude clean` and [`aptitude`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software)) downloaded *over 3.5GB of updates out of 4GB total* and stopped downloading rest of packages because `/` partition ran out of free space.

```
user@host:~# aptitude clean && df -h /var/cache/apt/archives/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8       7.3G  2.5G  4.4G  36% /
```

- Is there any way I can install 3.5GB of downloaded packages without need to run `aptitude clean` and *redownloading* them? How?

  I guess that some of the downloaded packages may depend on the packages that were not downloaded, so I would like to install only those that were downloaded with all of their dependencies.
- What is recommended size of the partition holding `/var/cache/apt/archives/`?
  Consider two variants of partitioning scheme: with and without separate `/var` partition<sup>*</sup>.

<sub>** As a side note: estimating size of the partitions was always troublesome for me – see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/442383/why-should-i-make-a-separate-partition-for-tmp) to learn why 1GB or even 3GB for `/tmp` partition may be not enough.*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can install 3.5GB of downloaded packages without need to run `aptitude clean` and *redownloading* them? How?

Not without a fair amount of effort, potentially, and perhaps some loss of information depending on how it’s done (I’m thinking of the “manually installed” status).

I would recommend running `aptitude autoclean` instead, and then re-running the upgrade: `autoclean` deletes packages which can no longer be downloaded. That way, you’ll keep all the packages that are needed for the upgrade.

> What is recommended size of the partition holding `/var/cache/apt/archives/`? Consider two variants of partitioning scheme: with and without separate `/var` partition.

In both cases, it depends on the amount of packages installed on the system being managed, and how frequently it’s upgraded. My main system has 12GiB of files in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, after `aptitude autoclean`...

For users who don’t care about the package cache at all, using `apt` might be interesting since it cleans up after itself by default.